# cisco, boot code update via SCP fails "no matching key exchange method found."

Tags: ssh, scp

Trying to update CISCO SF200-24 boot code via SCP, but all I get is

```
fatal: Unable to negotiate with <IP> port 5939: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
```

But my SSH

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
```

does offer them AFAICS:

```
$ ssh -Q kex
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
```

This is driving me nuts, especially as you have to enter all the data (IP of SCP host, filename, etc. over and over again with EVERY try) So what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The key exchange methods

```
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

are obsolete in the latest versions of OpenSSH and they are [not offered by default](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html). But you are able to specify then on command-line or in `ssh_config` to allow connecting to legacy servers (Cisco).

First way is on command-line:

```
scp  -O KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 host:file /local/path/
```

or better in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host your.cisco.host (or IP)
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

and then you are able to connect simple using

```
scp  your.cisco.host:file /local/path/
```

Edit: The `ssh -Q kex` lists supported algorithms, not the offered. You actually offered algorithms using `ssh -G host | grep kexalgorithms`

Comment: on mine, it's `KexAlgorthms` (not `KeyAlgorithms`).  x instead of y.

 `$ ssh -V
 OpenSSH_7.8p1 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`

works great, thanks!

Comment: @BillMcGonigle Sorry, that was indeed a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @Jakuje I have the exact problem, but when I used `sh -G host | grep kexalgorithms` i can see **diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1**, why am I still getting this issue?

Comment: @Abhinay probably some other algorithm is missing? Without seeing the whole error, it is hard to guess what went wrong for you.